# Mongoid: Limiting number of embedded objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I am using Mongoid with Rails 3. What would be the best way to limit the number of embedded objects (photos) that can be stored within each parent object (album)?

```
class Album
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :photos
end

class Photo
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :album, :inverse_of => :photos
end
```

With ActiveRecord, I would do something like:

```
has_many :photos, :before_add => :enforce_photo_limit

private

def enforce_photo_limit
  raise "Too many photos" if self.photos.count >= 50
end
```

...but this isn't supported by Mongoid.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoid includes [ActiveModel::Validations](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb), so you should be able to use the methods contained in that module:

```
class Album
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :photos

  validate :less_than_fifty_photos

  def less_than_fifty_photos
    errors.add(:base, "Too many photos") if self.photos.count >= 50
  end
end
```

**More info:** http://mongoid.org/docs/validation.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use validates_length_of and it should work.